# Why are pagenumbers centered with \pagestyle{headings} on \chapter{}'s first pages?

Tags: header-footer, chapters, page-numbering

I'm using documentclass `report` with options `twoside` and `openright`. The `pagestyle` is `headings`. This is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright]{report}
 \usepackage{blindtext}
 \pagestyle{headings}
 \begin{document}
  \chapter{Chapter}
   \blindtext \blindtext
   \section{Section}
    \blindtext \blindtext
 \end{document}
```

Why is the page number at the first page of the chapter centered at the bottom and not on the right even though the document style `headings` works on all other pages? How to move the page number on the first page of a chapter to the right side as it should be using the document option `openright`?

Comment: `\chapter` issues `\thispagestyle{plain}`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [page number position](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10043/12850).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the pages where chapters start are decorated with page style `plain`. That is why you get that behavior. If you want to change it, you have to redefine the page style `plain` like :

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright]{report}
 \usepackage{blindtext}
 \pagestyle{headings}

  \makeatletter
 \let\ps@plain\ps@headings
 \makeatother

 \begin{document}
  \chapter{Chapter}
   \blindtext \blindtext
   \section{Section}
    \blindtext \blindtext
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use different styles in different parts of your work, you can use the following code, which renews the command `\thispagestyle{plain}`.

In the following example, the page style is **"headings"** for all pages in the preface and acknowledgements section, including the title pages. In the rest of the document, title pages have the page style **"empty"** and all other pages have the page style headings.

```
\documentclass[twoside,english]{book}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{emptypage}          % no headlines on empty pages

% ***************************************************************
\newcommand\plainstyle{empty}% variable for page style
\newcommand\pagestyleTitlepages[1]{\renewcommand\plainstyle{#1}}
\let\thispagestyleold\thispagestyle
\renewcommand\thispagestyle[1]{%
  \def\textparam{#1}%
  \def\isplain{plain}%
  \ifx\textparam\isplain%
    \thispagestyleold{\plainstyle}%
  \else%
    \thispagestyleold{#1}%
  \fi%
}
% ***************************************************************

\begin{document}
  \chapter*{Preface}
  \pagenumbering{Roman}
  \pagestyleTitlepages{headings}

  \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext

  \chapter*{Acknowledgements}
  \blindtext

  \chapter{Chapter one}
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \pagestyleTitlepages{empty}

   \blindtext \blindtext
   \section{Section}
    \blindtext \blindtext

  \chapter{Chapter two}
   \blindtext \blindtext
   \section{Section}
    \blindtext \blindtext

 \end{document}
```