# How can I put the page numbers where I need them?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I need to put the number for each page that is numbered at the top right hand corner of the document. Currently that condition is satisfied except for the first page of each chapter. That is, for the page that contains the title of the chapter the number is at the bottom (center) of the page. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: In the main LaTeX document classes that recognize a `\chapter` command, the first page of each chapter is given page style `plain` automatically, even if a different page style is in effect for "ordinary" pages. Do you use a package such as `fancyhdr` to create your custom "fancy" page style? If so, you could try issuing the command `\thispagestyle{fancy}` immediately after each `\chapter` directive.

Comment: change the plain format

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for the information, but the problem was not solved. In fact nothing changed in the document. Also I am using the fancyhdr package.

Comment: In that case, please edit your posting to provide a complete MWE. In particular, please indicate which document class you use and how you set up the look of the pages using `fancyhdr`.

Comment: @Mico: What is MWE? I use the following: \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}, \usepackage{fancyhdr}, \usepackage{tocloft}, \pagestyle{myheadings}.

Comment: Sorry for the jargon -- MWE is short for minimum working example.  Please indicate how you use the machinery of the `fancyhdr` package. The page style `myheadings` is provided by the document class. Incidentally, did you try the command `\thispagestyle{myheadings}` on the pages with chapter headings?

Comment: @Mico: Thank you the problem is solved when I put \thispagestyle{myheadings} on the pages with the chapter headings. However, the first page of the bibliography did not change. Let me post that as a separate question. Thanks again.

Comment: Related: [How to remove page numbers from first page of chapters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103567/5764)

Comment: related: [Why are pagenumbers centered with \pagestyle{headings} on \chapter{}'s first pages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54222/579)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default the first page of each `\chapter` is set using the `plain` page style under the basic [`book`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) and [`report`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls) document classes. To see why this is the case, consider the `\chapter` macro:

```
\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
```

Note the setting of `\thispagestyle{plain}`. If you wish to change that, you can either create a new page style and update `plain`.

- Creating a new style:

  Using [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) you can either use the default `fancy` page style or create your own. Here's how to create your own:

  ```
  \fancypagestyle{main}{
    \fancyhf{}% Clear all headers/footers
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}% Page in Right header
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Header rule
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
  }
  ```

  The usage with something like [`titleps`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps) is similar:

  ```
  \newpagestyle{main}{
    \sethead{}% Left header
      {}% Centre header
      {\thepage}% Right header
    \setfoot{}{}{}% Clear footer
    \setheadrule{.4pt}% Header rule
    \setfootrule{0pt}% Not footer rule
  }
  ```

  Now you either insert this style on the chapter pages manually using

  ```
  \chapter{My chapter}
  \thispagestyle{main}
  ```

  or you update this through a patch to be implemented globally. Here's a patch using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) (place this in your document preamble):

  ```
  \usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
  \patchcmd{\chapter}% <cmd>
    {plain}% <search>
    {main}% <replace>
    {}{}% <success><failure>
  ```
- Update `plain`:

  This is similar to the above solutions. For `fancyhdr`, use

  ```
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    % your new plain settings
  }
  ```

  For `titleps` use

  ```
  \renewpagestyle{plain}{%
    % your new plain settings
  }
  ```

The above changes slightly if you're using a two-side document setup. However, it changes drastically if you're using another document class.

Comment: This is a really great answer to a frequent question.