# A few questions about head & foot & page number

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I have a sample `.tex` file as below - in this file i have redefined the foot by using `fancyhdr` package. My questions as below:

1. The chapter page (in this example, say page 1 & page 5) don't have the foot I modified by `fancyhdr`. How can I make all pages use the same foot?
2. If I want the page begin from page 2, what should i do? for example, current page1 will be empty, and current page 2 will be page 1 and etc...

Hope I have put my question clearly.:)

```
    \documentclass{book}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\scriptsize \thepage}
    \fancyfoot[L]{\scriptsize hihi}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\scriptsize \leftmark}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{chapter1}
    \blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext
    \blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext
    \chapter{chapter2}
    \blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext
    \blindtext\blindtext\blindtext
    \end{document}
```

Comment: To 1st: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10043/page-number-position

Comment: To 2nd: see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501378/how-can-i-start-pagenumbers-where-the-first-section-occurs-in-latex

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have successfully solved my questions. :)