# Page number appears in the middle of page on every new chapter

Tags: formatting, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I currently use Latex for a simple paper that's based on the extbook class. My source code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{extbook}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[paperheight = 18cm, paperwidth = 11.5cm, outer=1.5cm, inner = 1.5cm, top = 1.3cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}}{20pt}{\large}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{wholeBook}{
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{}

}

\pagestyle{wholeBook}
\begin{document}
\sloppy
\input{Chapters/Chapter1.tex}
\input{Chapters/Chapter2.tex}
... etc
\end{document}
```

This is meant to produce a page number on the left side of every even page and on the right of every odd page. Oddly enough, it produces unexpected output: For every first page of a chapter, the page number appears *in the middle* of the page.

I don't want this, yet I have no clue how to disable it. Does anybody here have a solution?

Comment: I tries `texdoc extbook` with no useful result. Where is the `extbook` class defined and available?

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/extsizes . This is only a class that modifies the font sizes, otherwise it's exactly like the standard book class. It produces the same faulty output if you use the normal book class instead of extbook.

Comment: chapter opening pages use `plain` page style, so you need to redefine that (the fancyhdr documentation has some special notes about that)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10043/page-number-position/458806#458806

Comment: Ah, thanks, exactly what I needed, that did the trick.